# Android Set wrap_content to ImageView by java code prob

Tags: android, imageview, classcastexception, layoutparams

I have set a Bitmap to an ImageView and then want to set wrap_content for both width and height.

```
imgSubsegment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.subsegment);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

......................................

imgSubsegmentSensor.setImageBitmap(bmpSubsegmentSensor);
imgSubsegmentSensor.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
```

It is giving `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams`

What is the problem in my code? How to solve?

Comment: What is the type of imgSubsegmentSensor? Have you tried Project -> Clean?

Comment: Read the exception... `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams` - you need a `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

.................

imgSubsegmentSensor.setImageBitmap(bmpSubsegmentSensor);
    imgSubsegmentSensor.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
```

It works.

Comment: I have a custom ImageView in which I am zooming, moving and rotating the image. And in main activity I am making Imageviews dynamically. When I applied your method, my imageview is not showing. Note: I have set the "ScaleType" to "Matrix". Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

```
    imgSubsegment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.subsegment);

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams imageViewParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ......................................

    imgSubsegmentSensor.setImageBitmap(bmpSubsegmentSensor);
    imgSubsegmentSensor.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
```

Try this.